# Finding the shortest path between any two nodes belonging to two disjoint subsets of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

There is an undirected graph in which every node is assigned some color. I have to find the shortest path from any blue colored node to any red colored node. (Other colors may also exist in the graph and although it doesnt matter but it is not known how many colors are there.) How can I do it in polynomial time?

Comment: I am sure Dijkstra algorithm can be used in some way to solve this, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a hint, add two new nodes to the graph- call them s and t.  Connect s to each blue node with an edge of cost 0 and each red node to t with an edge of cost 0.  Then find the shortest path from s to t.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Polynomial both for adding the s and t nodes and for finding the shortest path between them (e.g. with Dijkstra), so polynomial it is.

Comment: @lbp There is a lot of easy ways to solve it in polynomial time, you could do Floyd-Warshall and find the pair (blue,red) with minimum distance. You could do Dijkstra |red| * |blue| times, very inefficiently, and still be polynomial. But this answer gives an efficient way, not only polynomial.